# change default base language for iOS app in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, xcode, localization

My app supports **English & German**. So, when I set the system device language `english`, then it shows **English** & vice versa. I don't have add any preferred languages here, just one system language only **deleted all preferred languages**.

[settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hFI3z.png)

If I set system language as `French`, then the app always displays `English` only. **I need to set default language as `German` if unsupported system language is set.**

I already set `Localization native development region` to **German** and `developmentRegion` to **de** in `.pbxproj`, but still showing English text.

got the answer as here: https://medium.com/swlh/swiftui-localization-on-the-fly

Answer (score 0):

Try going to your `info.plist` file and changing the `Localization native development region` value to German

If you want to do this programmatically you can get the current user localization preferences with `Bundle.main.preferredLocalizations.first`, which will return an optional string with the current language preferred by the user.

`let language = Bundle.main.preferredLocalizations.first`

Comment: I already set `Localization native development region` to **German**, but still not working

Comment: @NickPatel You might find this [link](https://fluffy.es/introduction-to-localization/) useful